# Как заменить управляющий символ в строке на другой символ?

Tags: linux, c

Мне необходимо найти и заменить управляющий символ в исходной строке (будь то \n, \r, \t) на другой символ (например, пробел).

Мой код ничего не меняет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int j;
char *string = "This is the\nstring";
char *array = (char *)malloc(strlen(string));
*array = *string;

printf ("%s\n", string);

for(j = 0; j < strlen(array); j++)
    if ((*(array + j) == '\\')&&(*(array + j + 1) == 'n')) 
    {
        *(array + j) = ' ';
        *(array + j + 1) = ' ';
    }

printf ("%s\n", string);

return 0;
}
```

Укажите, пожалуйста, на мои ошибки.

Comment: а вас не смущает, что после `*array = *string;` у вас в `array` всего один символ? Т.е. в цикле у вас только один символ и будет проверен.

Comment: а самая главная ваша ошибка (если исправить инициализацию array): `printf ("%s\n", string);`, но при этом `*(array + j + 1) = ' '` Т.е. изменили одну строку, а вывели другую. И вы уже столько раз меняли код, оставьте его в покое ) Ваше `if (*(array + j) == '\n') *(array + j) = ' ';` не плохо справляется

Comment: @BOPOH большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки в приведенном коде.

1. Строка в C заканчивается символом `'\0' (0)`. Это необходимо учитывать при выделении памяти под строки: `malloc(strlen(s)+1)`.
2. В C нет встроенного механизма для копирования массивов, поэтому конструкция `*array = *string` не будет работать так, как по-видимому ожидается. Для копирования массивов и строк можно использовать стандартные библиотечные функции: `memcpy` и `strcpy` соответственно.

Еще хочу заметить, что вместо `*(array+j)` можно писать `array[j]` - в C очень тесная связь между указателями и массивами. Также, необходимо понимать, что код написан так, что может выполняться сравнение элементов за концом строки - если последний символ равен `\`. В данном конкретном случае ничего плохого не случится (т.к. в конце строки должен быть нулевой символ), однако нужно это хорошо понимать, чтобы не повторить такой ошибки при работе уже с обычными массивами.

Answer (score 4):

В строке "This is the\nstring" на самом деле не содержится два идущих подряд символа '\' и 'n'. Последовательность "\n" называется Escape-последовательностью и преобразуется в байт 0x0A при компиляции. Соответственно, вам нужно искать байт 0x0A и менять его.

Comment: *нужно искать байт 0x0A* — он же — символ `\n`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а, ну да. Можно искать '\n', чего я в самом деле...

Answer (score 2):

До кучи:

```
char *array = (char *)malloc(strlen(string));
*array = *string;
```

здесь 2 ошибки. Должно быть либо:

```
char *array = (char *)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
strcpy(array, string);
```

либо просто:

```
char *array = string;
```

Comment: И совсем уж до кучи, просто `char *array = strdup(string);` (а вот с `char *array = string;` ТС получит segfault при попытке изменить символ в константе).